# Command to detect if internet connection is wired or wireless

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I would like a command to check if my internet connection is wired or wireless. I am using Arch Linux. I am doing this to display a different icon in lemonbar for different network configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general case your network can be configured in the way, that you simultaneously have wireless and wired connection. 
E.g. part of your routes goes via wireless connection and the other part goes via wired.

I would detect it in the following way:

1. Identify the address which might be an indicator of network connection type (e.g. public google dns 8.8.8.8)
2. Check what interface is used to reach this address from this command:

   ip route get 8.8.8.8
3. Get information about interface like described in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060638/1466222)

Comment: `[ ip route list | grep -Po 'default.*dev \K\w' == 'w' ] && echo wireless || echo wired`

Comment: @Costas, it will not work. e.g. I have 2 `default.*dev` rows in `ip r l` on my laptop which apparantely breaks your command. and also interface can be renamed (eg. I had default eht3 as wireless interface on my dell laptop) which will break the logic.

Comment: @Costas It works but I get all kinds of errors like `grep: ==: no such file or directory` and `grep: w: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Marcel it is because `grep` returns 2 lines and construction in brackets doesn't work in correct way. probably it returned `wired` and you're just lucky to use wired connection now. Did you try to switch to wireless and run the command?

Comment: `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep -Po 'dev \K\w+' | grep -qFf - /proc/net/wireless && echo wireless || echo wired`

Comment: @rush Can't. It's a vm for now.

Comment: @Costas That seems to work but I can't test if for wireless.

Answer (score 2):

To list the currently available network connections:

command line

```
nmcli con show
```

the output is somthing like:

[image]